# How to convert table to interaction list in python

Tags: python, list, correlation

I have a correlation table from another tool. I want to convert this table into lists of correlations in python. For example, from this dataframe

```
   A   B   C  
A  1  -0.4 -0.8
B -0.4 1   0.5
C -0.8 0.5 1
```

into

```
A A 1
A B -0.4
A C -0.8
B B 1
B C 0.5
C C 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to show your code(What you have tried so far?)

Comment: I tried in on excel but it makes me exhausted

Comment: `df.stack()` , it would work for your case

Comment: I will add it to answer, please close the question

Comment: @Nagakiran How to close the question? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and `Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 50 close votes per day. When a question reaches 3 close votes, it is marked as being Closed, and will no longer accept answers.`

Comment: Sry @Maetha, I meant to accept the answer so it closes from developer attention. Thanks for your response :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.stack()` to achieve the desired output

```
   A   B   C  
A  1  -0.4 -0.8
B -0.4 1   0.5
C -0.8 0.5 1

df.stack()
```

Out:

```
A A 1
A B -0.4
A C -0.8
B B 1
B C 0.5
C C 1
```